# How can I maintain IBOutlet variable data when switching between views

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

Short version:
How can I "snapshot" my game's status when leaving that view and restore it in its exact state when going back into the view? Or simply maintain the values regardless of my current view?

Long version:
I have a "settings" view with its own view controller and a "game" view with its own view controller. I'd like to be able to switch back to settings to make a change to the game without reinitializing all my IBOutlets and their values in my game view when I go back.

I understand that it's where the variables are declared and thus will have to reinitialize when called but I even tried defining them in their declaration with global variables that I can update on "viewDidDisappear" but the values/attributes don't seem to populate. I would think there has to be a way to retain these values (or the games current status) in memory without deallocating when the view disappears.

I've added some sample code wherein the issue can be replicated though I don't think it's so much a problem with the code as it with my limited understanding of its functionality and/or capabilities.

Thanks in advance for any help that leads to a solution!

I have a custom class for my game pieces:

```
class gamePiece: UILabel {

    var face = "face"

    func updateFace() {

        self.text = self.face

    }
}

var isGameOver = true

var allLabels = [gamePiece]()
```

My gameViewController looks like this:

```
class gameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var l1: gamePiece!
    @IBOutlet var l2: gamePiece!
    @IBOutlet var l3: gamePiece!
    @IBOutlet var l4: gamePiece!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {

        l1.face = "hello world"
        l1.updateFace()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if isGameOver {

            allLabels = [l1, l2, l3, l4]

            isGameOver = false

        } else {

            l1.text = allLabels[0].text!
            l2.text = allLabels[1].text!
            l3.text = allLabels[2].text!
            l4.text = allLabels[3].text!

            allLabels = [l1, l2, l3, l4]

        }

        for label in allLabels {

            label.updateFace()

        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        allLabels = [l1, l2, l3, l4]

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

The expectation is that `l1.text` would render "hello world". Instead it renders "face"; the default value of an object of that my `gamePiece` class.

I'm sure this is a simple fix.. I just think it's so close to my face I can't see it.

Comment: The general strategy is to use a MVC app structure.  The 'M' part is the data model, which should exist outside your views and controllers.  Exactly how you implement it is a big topic...and much of the reason why people argue about user defaults, core data, singletons, shared instances and other things.  But step one is to get the data out of your controller and into an independent object that's not linked to the controller's life cycle.

Comment: That's one of the weird things about it. I have tried to "stow away" the data and update the values when the view loads but I couldn't get that to work either. Seems like it should be simple.

Comment: Maybe show how the "stow away" and refresh code is implemented?

Comment: Well, the short version is when the game view loads (viewDidLoad) I append each of my buttons to an array that is declared outside of any class; lets call it "gamePieces." 

When the view loads again, for any reason, I have the viewDidLoad check if the game is over, if it's not to set each of the IBOutlets back to each of the items in the array I declared earlier. I'm able to see the values in the array have remained but the game pieces don't seem to get the values assigned to them. i.e., they should have Int value and when I call my global array it's there when I call the game piece it's not

Comment: I tried to recreate it with some sample code without going into all the complexities of my game but I couldn't replicate it. I've been looking at this for hours each day and haven't found a reasonable solution. Any solution, actually. Ha!

Comment: Correction. I was able to replicate. The issue seems to rest in that I'm using a custom class. See sample code added to OP.

Comment: It's not clear what class owns `allLabels`.  As I mentioned in my first comment, these should be held outside the controller.

Comment: In this example, no class owns allLabels. It's declared at top level.

Comment: @PhillipMills, in regards to your first comment, my model is outside of the life cycle of the controller. The IBOutlets, however, are not. Something is not allowing me to reassign my model's values to the UI elements before or after the view appears. They end up just showing the storyboards default setup of that UI element.

Comment: I found the link below and it sounds like what I would want but I'm either not implementing it right or it's not the solution. 

[Preserving and Restoring State](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH28-SW1)